# Python multiprocessing pipe will not recv() properly in PyDev, works fine anywhere else

Tags: eclipse, pydev

This is from another question I had. I discovered that this error only occurs in PyDev. If I run the code from the command line or from IDLE, the proper output is produced. In PyDev, nothing happens:

This is for Python 3.2.2, Eclipse 3.7.2:

```
from multiprocessing import Pipe, Process

def f(r):
    print(r.recv())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    q, r = Pipe()
    p = Process(target=f, args=(r,))
    p.start()
    q.send([42, None, 'hello'])
    p.join()
```

The main thread creates a new `Process`, `p`, and sends `r`, a bidirectional connection object, to function `f()`. When process `p` is started, I expect `r.recv()` to block (which, as far as I understand, means that this process will wait indefinitely until something comes through the pipe) until the main process sends some objects through with `q.send`.

Then `p.join()` should make the main process wait until `p` has run its course.

But nothing whatsoever happens. If I add a `print` statement to `f()`, nothing happens there, either, as if `f()` never even runs and `p.start()` is nonfunctional.

Can you explain why this won't work in PyDev and what might be fixed?