# Multiprocessing beside a main loop

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm struggling with a issue for some time now.
I'm building a little script which uses a main loop. This is a process that needs some attention from the users. The user responds on the steps and than some magic happens with use of some functions

Beside this I want to spawn another process which monitors the computer system for some specific events like pressing specif keys. If these events occur then it will launch the same functions as when the user gives in the right values.

So I need to make two processes:
-The main loop (which allows user interaction)
-The background "event scanner", which searches for specific events and then reacts on it.

I try this by launching a main loop and a daemon multiprocessing process. The problem is that when I launch the background process it starts, but after that I does not launch the main loop.
I simplified everything a little to make it more clear:

```
import multiprocessing, sys, time

def main_loop():
    while 1:
        input = input('What kind of food do you like?')
        print(input)

def test():
    while 1:
        time.sleep(1)
        print('this should run in the background')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        print('hello!')
        mProcess = multiprocessing.Process(target=test())
        mProcess.daemon = True
        mProcess.start()
        #after starting main loop does not start while it prints out the test loop fine.
        main_loop() 
    except:
        sys.exit(0)
```

Comment: I cut and pasted your code and it worked in my environment. How do you launch it? This is strange. Oh, and under what OS are you working?

PS: a little tip (I guess you come from C programming): `while True` is way more understandable and clear than `while 1`. Plus I guess that Python has to evaluate one less expression this way.

Comment: I developed it in pyDev under a Windows 8 x64 enviroment with python 3.3.

I also made a small mistake. Now the main loop also has a 1/true in it. 
Now it doesn't work like it should. The problem is it starts saying now: This should run in the background, but it doesn't ask which food I like. The main loop is not executed and it keeps stuck at that point while test runs. Can you look at it again?

Beside this, thanks for the while true instead of while 1 tip!

Comment: my answer below explains why it doesn't `ask which food I like`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should do

`mProcess = multiprocessing.Process(target=test)`

instead of

`mProcess = multiprocessing.Process(target=test())`

Your code actually calls `test` in the parent process, and that call never returns.

Comment: Yep, the inifinit loop in the main process.

Comment: When I apply this it doesn't print "this should run in the background". Why does the test function not run? Or does it run, but does it not print?

Comment: Okay it runs sometimes when I launch it directly, so I will accept this answer. However it takes a long time before it runs. Is there a possibility to make it start faster? In pyDev it even starts rarely.

Comment: Nevermind. There is a bug in pyDev which makes it difficult to work with multiprocessing. Just like here occured: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10464946/python-multiprocessing-pipe-will-not-recv-properly-in-pydev-works-fine-anywhe

Beside this a process starts slowly, but I solved this by checking if the process is alive and afterwards launching the main loop.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the locking synchronization to have a better control over your program's flow. Curiously, the input function raise an EOF error, but I'm sure you can find a workaround.

```
import multiprocessing, sys, time

def main_loop(l):
    time.sleep(4)
    l.acquire()

    # raise an EOFError, I don't know why .
    #_input = input('What kind of food do you like?') 

    print(" raw input at 4 sec ")
    l.release()

    return

def test(l):
    i=0
    while i<8:
        time.sleep(1)

        l.acquire()
        print('this should run in the background : ', i+1,  'sec')
        l.release()

        i+=1

    return



if __name__ == '__main__':

    lock = multiprocessing.Lock()


    #try:
    print('hello!')
    mProcess = multiprocessing.Process(target=test, args = (lock, ) ).start()

    inputProcess = multiprocessing.Process(target=main_loop, args = (lock,)).start()



    #except:
        #sys.exit(0)
```