# Python - Daemon process with Multiprocessing or multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing, python-daemon

I have a `Python` script which executes an infinite loop (it watches a folder for certain file types).

Once a file type is found, I need it to spawn a new process to process the file.
I began to implement this code already (posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20977573/python-calling-multiprocessing-pool-inside-a-daemon), but now I'm asking a different question about the same topic - not necessarily the same code - hence posting a new question).

However, this infinite loop script needs to run in the background. In my previous question, I implemented this with the infinte loop running in a daemon process, and then the file processing (once a file of a particular type was found) spawned a new process with the `mutliprocessing.pool` module. However, I found out the hard way that daemon processes cannot start new sub processes.

What might be the best way to implement this functionality???

**Is there a better way to get an infinite loop to run in the background and still be able to start new processes with `multiprocessing.pool`?**

Comment: Maybe look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15429323/multiprocessing-beside-a-main-loop

Comment: @maxywb This isn't really answering the same problem. I need a process to run in the background, which can then selectively start new processes.

Comment: Well you do have the equivalent of a main loop, it's just a background process, which should be a minor difference.